# How to sort files by creation time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I'm creating a program which has to sort a lot of files by the creation time. But I was unable to find a solution. Is there a way to find the file creation time in flutter? If yes then we will be able to sort the file list using creation times.

Answer (score -1):

As jamesdlin suggested, you can try File.stat()

Mine here is a custom solution to create an object with a File and a field with the current time when it's constructor is called

```
import 'dart:io';

class FileWithCreationTime {

  File file;
  late DateTime creationTime;

  FileWithCreationTime (this.file){
    creationTime = DateTime.now();
  }
}
```

and then

```
    List<FileWithCreationTime > sortedFileList = [];
    sortedFileList.sort((b,a)=> a.creationTime.compareTo(b.creationTime));
```

Comment: I think you would want to extract the file creation time with `File.stat()`, not with the current time.

Comment: You are right. I did not know about the dart FileStat class. I change my answer accordingly